# Creating a pandas Dataframe from loops in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a file containing a yearly dataset from 1987 to 2008 each in its ".csv" format. I would love to have a loop that reads each file to the pandas DataFrame and name it according to filename excluding the CSV extension.

I have tried this:

```
flight_data = []

df_lists = []

for flights_file in glob.glob("../datasets/*.csv"):

    flight_data.append(flights_file)

    df_lists.append('df_'+flights_file.split("\\")[-1][:-4:])
```

but I am stuck in trying to read it to a dataframe and calling it subsequently.

I am trying to use a loop to avoid loading each file individually like:

```
df_1988 = pd.read_csv("../datasets/1988.csv")

df_1989 = pd.read_csv("../datasets/1989.csv")
 
df_1990 = pd.read_csv("../datasets/1990.csv")

df_1991 = pd.read_csv("../datasets/1991.csv")

df_1992 = pd.read_csv("../datasets/1992.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for file in glob.glob("../datasets/*.csv"):

df = pd.read_csv(file)

df.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'dep_time', 'sched_dep_time', 'dep_delay',
       'arr_time', 'sched_arr_time', 'arr_delay', 'carrier', 'flight',
       'tailnum', 'origin', 'dest', 'air_time', 'distance', 'hour', 'minute',
       'time_hour']

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot lucky,  looking at the file from the glob extract, not all the csv files have the same column names. some are Index(['iata', 'airport', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'lat', 'long'], dtype='object') and there are 26 csv files am trying to read using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot dynamically declare variables with names like df_1990, df_1991... We can however, use a dictionary to store your DataFrames as follows:

```
all_df = {}
for file in glob.glob("../datasets/*.csv"):
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    df.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'dep_time', 'sched_dep_time', 'dep_delay',
           'arr_time', 'sched_arr_time', 'arr_delay', 'carrier', 'flight',
           'tailnum', 'origin', 'dest', 'air_time', 'distance', 'hour', 'minute',
           'time_hour']
    file_name = file[file.rfind("/") + 1: file.find(".")] #Extract name of file
    all_df[file_name ] = df
```

**NOTE:** Assuming that the filenames are unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, looking at the file from the glob extract, not all the csv files have the same column names. some are for example having Index(['iata', 'airport', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'lat', 'long'], dtype='object') and there are 26 csv files am trying to read using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of ‘exec()’ for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'A'],
    [2,'B']
])
for file in files:
    df.to_csv(file)
    
for file in glob.glob('file*.csv'):
    dfname = file.replace(".csv","")
    dfinput = pd.read_csv(file)
    exec(f'{dfname} = dfinput.copy()')
```

this will define dataframes file1, file2, file3:

```
>>> file1
   Unnamed: 0  0  1
0           0  1  A
1           1  2  B
>>> file2
   Unnamed: 0  0  1
0           0  1  A
1           1  2  B
>>> file3
   Unnamed: 0  0  1
0           0  1  A
1           1  2  B
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. I actually did try the exec(), but I got a 'utf-8' error while running the code, and it takes a lot of system resources.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
df_flights=[] #Initializing lists of dataframes

for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin-1')    
    df_flights.append(df)

flights_df = pd.concat(df_flights, ignore_index=True)
```